# Build menu from MS Word XML

Tags: javascript, jquery, xml, ms-word

I've recently assembled some jQuery that allows a user to build out a bulleted list in MS Word with hyperlinks and turn that into a HTML unordered list.  Ideas for uses are website menu systems where the user may not have a clue about HTML. You can also extend this with jQuery UI plugins for effects.  Looking for edge cases.

```
/*
    The following will read in a bullet list from in a MS Word XML file and turn it into a 
    unordered list with hyperlinks. Perhaps to use as a menu.
*/
$.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    async: false,
    url: "Menu.xml",
    dataType: "xml",
    success:function(results){
        var currentDepth = 0;
        $("#menu").append('<ul class="menuLvl'+currentDepth+'"></ul>');
        $(results).find("[nodeName=w:p]").each(function(){
            if($(this).find("[nodeName=w:pStyle]").attr('w:val') == 'ListParagraph'){
                var liValue = $(this).find("[nodeName=w:t]").text();
                var hyper = $(this).find("[nodeName=w:hyperlink]").attr('r:id');
                var placeAtDepth = parseInt($(this).find("[nodeName=w:ilvl]").attr('w:val'), 10);

                if(placeAtDepth > currentDepth){
                    $(".menuLvl"+ currentDepth).append('<ul class="menuLvl'+ placeAtDepth +'">');
                }   

                currentDepth = placeAtDepth;

                //Determine if we have an hyperlink
                if(hyper != null){
                    var link = $(results).find('Relationship[Id='+hyper+']').attr('Target');
                    liValue = '<a href="'+ link +'">'+ liValue +'</a>';
                }

                $(".menuLvl"+currentDepth).last().append('<li>'+ liValue +'</li>');
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Looks fine (maybe some stricter formatting could help readibility, but not an issue), so I'll suggest completely optional improvements that might help spotting important improvements.

As a general principle, try to [be ready for bogus values in your input so you can avoid generating nonsense](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Robustness_principle). Being more robust will also make reusing your code for somewhat different tasks easier.

```
$.ajax({
/// [...]
    success:function(results){
/// [...]
        $(results).find("[nodeName=w:p]").each(function(){
            if($(this).find("[nodeName=w:pStyle]").attr('w:val') == 'ListParagraph'){
                var liValue = $(this).find("[nodeName=w:t]").text();
/// -^ What if the input has an empty value here? Skip? 

                var hyper = $(this).find("[nodeName=w:hyperlink]").attr('r:id');
                var placeAtDepth = parseInt($(this).find("[nodeName=w:ilvl]").attr('w:val'), 10);
/// -^ parseInt can return a NaN, maybe you want to bail out in that case?
///    Should also handle some bogus results for .find.

                if(placeAtDepth > currentDepth){
                    $(".menuLvl"+ currentDepth).append('<ul class="menuLvl'+ placeAtDepth +'">');
                }

                currentDepth = placeAtDepth;

                //Determine if we have an hyperlink
                if(hyper != null){
                    var link = $(results).find('Relationship[Id='+hyper+']').attr('Target');
/// -^ This can result in an invalid link for broken input. But what if
       the input is malicious (JS hrefs)? 

                    liValue = '<a href="'+ link +'">'+ liValue +'</a>';
```